# After reinstalling Commerce kickstart I can't get editors to be seen

Tags: wysiwyg, commerce

Drupal 7.25 with latest Commerce Kickstart just won't show editors after reinstall.  Tried CKeditor 3.6 and 3.5. Tinymce also.

I went through all the help install files I could find a solution.  What am I missing?

Comment: Check your javascript console log, sounds like a JS error.

Comment: Check you status page of the instance, may be library issue.